# Include statement in a Fortran file

Tags: fortran

I had a Fortran module file (filename.F), which contains a line of statement:

```
#include "module_io_domain_defs.inc"
```

which I don't quite understand. Why is a "#" symbol. Should not be just

```
include "module_io_domain_defs.inc"
```

I know during the compilation process, the *.F file becomes *.f90 file. How to understand the above statement and how dose the compilation process work?

Comment: cpp style pre-processing isn't standard Fortran, but there are a few minimum requirements imposed by usage such as OpenMP.  Source files named with .F are treated as .f, thus defaulting to f77 fixed form.  On OS such as Windows, which don't distinguish between .F and .f, cpp pre-processing can be invoked only by those options like -cpp/fpp.  So if you wish pre-processing to make a .f90 file by default, you start with .F90 (on linux....).

Comment: Since you ask, typically, cpp style pre-processing is done by a separate program.  It may or may not be one provided with a C compiler; e.g. gfortran -E is the same as gcc -E -traditional.  -traditional means a CPP which ignores /.  On Windows, making a visible pre-processed copy of a source file works only when writing it into a separate folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#` designates a C preprocessor directive. Therefore the `#include` is not processed by the Fortran compiler but by a C preprocessr (`cpp`, [c-preprocessor](/questions/tagged/c-preprocessor)). The capital `.F` instead of `f` typically tells the compiler to run `cpp` before compiling.

The main difference is that the file included by `#include` will again be processed by `cpp`, whereas a file included just by `include` will not be processed by anything before compiling.

The preprocessor can also be requested by passing a flag such as `-cpp` or `-fpp` if the compiler does not recognize the capital `F` in the suffix.