# gfortran does not process #define in include

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran, preprocessor

While trying to rebuild some ancient Fortran code using gfortran 10.2.0, I get the following from an include that contains a preprocessor #define:

```
$ gfortran preproc.f
minimal.inc:1:2:

    1 | #define UD_POINTER integer*8
      |  1
Warning: Illegal preprocessor directive
minimal.inc:2:7:

    2 |       UD_POINTER utmake
      |       1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

The minimal source file preproc.f looks like this:

```
      program preproc
      include 'minimal.inc'
      end program
```

...and minimal.inc is:

```
#define UD_POINTER      integer*8
      UD_POINTER utmake
```

The "Unclassifiable statement" error is obviously a consequence of the "Illegal preprocessor directive" warning.  If I simply copy the 'include' contents into the source file it works fine, but this is not a suitable solution because I want to maintain separation of code between the application and the library where the include is from.

Adding `-cpp` does not change anything.  Changing gcc/gfortran versions to as far back as 4.8.5 does not fix it.  I haven't found a compiler flag that touches it.  What's going on here?  What can I do to get it to comprehend that `#define`?

Comment: You need to replace `include 'minimal.inc'` with `#include "minimal.inc"`. See [Include statement in a Fortran file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456342/include-statement-in-a-fortran-file).

Comment: It had not occurred to me that the Fortran include statement and the CPP #include directive were distinct.  Files included via the Fortran statement do not undergo further preprocessing, hence the #define was not picked up, hence the error. Thank you very much!